# OpenCV import error mac

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to install OpenCV on my Mac (OS High Sierra), following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@nuwanprabhath/installing-opencv-in-macos-high-sierra-for-python-3-89c79f0a246a) with some minor modifications. For completeness, so far I have done the following:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH >> /.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

brew install python python3
brew link python
brew link python3
brew postinstall python3

pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 >> /.bashrc
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Develsource/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh >> /.bashrc
brew install opencv
echo /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python3.6/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencv3.pth
```

This all seems to work fine. In the above I changed the tutorial's `WORKON_HOME` to `virtualenvs` rather than `virtualenvsexport`.

Then I go in to my virtual env:

```
mkvirtualenv cv-py3 -p python3
workon cv-py3
pip install numpy scipy scikit-image matplotlib scikit-learn
deactivate
```

Now I go back and link OpenCV:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv-py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/opencv@3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so cv2.so
```

Now comes the problem:

```
workon cv-py3
python3
import cv2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/JosephBullock/.virtualenvs/cv-py3test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tesseract/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_3/lib/libopencv_text.3.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

It is here that I'm not sure what's gone wrong and what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the library "tesseract". Execute the following command:

```
brew install tesseract
```